# Not able to build android apk in react native expo project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, react-native

I am trying to build an apk from an existing expo project.

For that I ejected the expo project and also generated the keystore files and kept it successfully in the project.

Now I ran the command `gradlew assembleRelease` in the android folder but the terminal gives the following error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'rnapp'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.4/builder-3.1.4.jar'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.1.4/sdk-common-26.1.4.jar'.
> > Connection reset

This is the `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
     repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

I am expecting a build of the project as Apk file.

Comment: Did you eject because of the build or because you had native code / packages?

Comment: No I don't have any native code/packages. I created a simple app in expo and ejected it to build my apk.

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score -2):

Building an apk in an expo project is **much** easier than building an ejected / native project...

This is one of the major advantages using expo.

You shouldn't eject it, then, but build it using `expo build:android` or `expo build:ios`.

The full details are here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/

Comment: Just got to see this today. Is there any way I can build my ejected app because if I would have to add any native package in case ?

Comment: Then this is another thing, more complicated, but doable, obviously, done for many projects. You will find lots of info about it here and in many other websites.

Comment: I didn't find any workable answer.  Can you please explain?

Comment: I literally can't find any information about building production apps on CI server with Expo Bare Workflow. Can you share at least some links?

Comment: @AmanRathore my apologies, I missed your comment from Apr 22, 2019... Saw it only today when the last comment has been posted.
You have probably found a solution long ago.

Comment: @webdevbyjoss CI = ?

Comment: @Yossi continuous integration